# Gridview RowUpdating Error - Index was out of range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

When I click the "Update" button in the gridview, it fire the RowUpdating event, but it returns a error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

The following is the vb code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)
        Dim Col1_SL As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("cb1_SL"), CheckBox)

.................       

        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim sql As String
        Dim reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

        Using conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("hris_shiftdutyConnectionString").ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            sql = "SET DATEFORMAT dmy;UPDATE troster SET SL='" & Convert.ToInt32(Col1_SL.Checked) & "' where roster_key='" & Col1_RosterKey.Text & "';"
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            conn.Close()
            reader.Close()
        End Using

        'Reset the edit index.
        Gridview1.EditIndex = -1

        'Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData()
    End If

End Sub
```

Please help. Thanks
Joe

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled for the control? Are you databinding the GridView only when the page is not being posted back?

Comment: In my gridview, i had disable the viewstate EnableViewState="False" and in page_load i bind the gridview if it is not post back        (If Not IsPostBack Then)

Comment: if i enable the ViewState, it will return an error "Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request." when clicking the Update button. So I need to set it = FALSE

Comment: Please see my answer. If you post the code that shows how you are databinding the control from the Page_Load, along with the BindData method, I might be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ViewState is disabled and you are only databinding when the page is not being posted back, this line is always going to fail:

`Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)`

as the count on `Gridview1.Rows` is going to be 0.

When the page is posted back to the server, ASP.NET needs the ViewState to be enabled for the control so it can recreate the controls and properly determine which events to raise, which control values have changed, etc. You should enable the ViewState, and you'll have to figure out what is causing the control tree error. There must be some other modification that is taking place in the code.

Keep in mind that only databinding the GridView in Page_Load when the page is not posted back is correct, but you won't be able to properly handle events unless you enable ViewState on the control.

Comment: Thanks, I had set the enableviewstate to true now. The Index was out of range error fixed.

But when running the RowUpdating event, it get the upper row data.

For example, I edit the 2nd row (e.rowindex = 1), but it get the 1st row (e.rowindex=0) value.