# Downloading a file from SQL Server - ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, download, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to download files from an SQL Server 2012 database using GridView. I am getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` giving me this error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

on:

```
Dim fileid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
```

**Code concerned:**

```
 Protected Sub lnkDownload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim lnkbtn As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = TryCast(lnkbtn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim fileid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
        Dim name As String, type As String
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True;")

        con.Open()



        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "Select content_name, content_type, content_file from content where content_id=@Id"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", fileid)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()

            Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)

            If dt IsNot Nothing Then

                download(dt)

            End If

        End Using

    End Sub


    Public Function GetData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As DataTable

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringDb1").ConnectionString()

        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)

        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Connection = con

        Try

            con.Open()

            sda.SelectCommand = cmd

            sda.Fill(dt)

            Return dt

        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write(ex.Message)

            Return Nothing

        Finally

            con.Close()

            sda.Dispose()

            con.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Function


    Protected Sub download(ByVal dt As DataTable)

        Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())

        Response.Buffer = True

        Response.Charset = ""

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & dt.Rows(0)("Name").ToString())

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)

        Response.Flush()

        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

**`gvrow.RowIndex`**  at time of debugging is **0**.

**Full Code:**

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.IO

```
Partial Class Documents
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnUploadContent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadContent.Click

        Dim filePath As String = FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName

        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)

        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)

        Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty



        Select Case ext

            Case ".doc"

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"

                Exit Select

            Case ".docx"

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"

                Exit Select

            Case ".xls"

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

                Exit Select

            Case ".xlsx"

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

                Exit Select

            Case ".jpg"

                contenttype = "image/jpg"

                Exit Select

            Case ".png"

                contenttype = "image/png"

                Exit Select

            Case ".gif"

                contenttype = "image/gif"

                Exit Select

            Case ".pdf"

                contenttype = "application/pdf"

                Exit Select

        End Select

        If contenttype <> String.Empty Then

            Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream

            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)

            Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)



            'insert the file into database


            Dim strQuery As String = "INSERT INTO [master_db].[dbo].[content] ([content_name],[content_type],[content_file]) VALUES (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value() = contenttype

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes

            InsertUpdateData(cmd)

            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully"

        Else

            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." + " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats"

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub lnkDownload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim lnkbtn As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = TryCast(lnkbtn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim fileid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
        Dim name As String, type As String
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True;")

        con.Open()



        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "Select content_name, content_type, content_file from content where content_id=@Id"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", fileid)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()

            Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)

            If dt IsNot Nothing Then

                download(dt)

            End If

        End Using

    End Sub


    Public Function GetData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As DataTable

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringDb1").ConnectionString()

        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)

        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Connection = con

        Try

            con.Open()

            sda.SelectCommand = cmd

            sda.Fill(dt)

            Return dt

        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write(ex.Message)

            Return Nothing

        Finally

            con.Close()

            sda.Dispose()

            con.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Function


    Protected Sub download(ByVal dt As DataTable)

        Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())

        Response.Buffer = True

        Response.Charset = ""

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & dt.Rows(0)("Name").ToString())

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)

        Response.Flush()

        Response.End()

    End Sub



    Public Function InsertUpdateData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean

        Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringDb1").ConnectionString()

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True;")

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Connection = conn

        Try

            conn.Open()

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write(ex.Message)

            Return False

        Finally

            conn.Close()

            conn.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

What is happening and why?

Comment: What is the value of `gvrow.RowIndex`?  Have you stepped through the code with the debugger?

Comment: @Tim Hi, `gvrow.RowIndex` is 0.

Comment: have you tried the fix in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488359/gridview-rowupdating-error-index-was-out-of-range ?

Comment: @RandomUs1r Yes, I have set EnableViewState to true to no avail.

Comment: fair enough, let me see if I can post a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

replace the error line with this:

```
Dim selectedRow As Integer = Me.GridView1.CurrentRow.Index

Dim fileid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Me.GridView1.Item(1,gvrow.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
```

Replace the number 1 with the index of the cell that contains the fileid (ie if its the 0 for the first cell, 1 for the second and so on)

Let me know if this works. Am a C# developer so conversions may differ.

Comment: `Dim selectedRow As Integer = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex` gives me this error ` (NullReferenceException) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: kindly check this : "GridView1.CurrentRow.Index" not "GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex"

Answer (score 0):

pass the RowIndex via CommandArgument and use it to retrieve the DataKey value

add the below line on Button

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
```

and add the below line on  Server Event

```
    Dim Index As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
    Dim val As String = DirectCast(Me.grid.DataKeys(Index)("YourDataKeyName"), String)
```

**Update:**

See this samples :

[sample1](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/01/rowindex-gridview-rowcommand-datakey.html)

[sample 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/01/08/get-primary-key-on-row-command-gridview.aspx)

Comment: Hi. Wat would be the VB.NET code for the second part of the code?

Comment: Ok Thanks. And Server Event would be Page_Load ? And what should I replace "YourDataKeyName" with ?

Comment: Server Event means onrowcommand event .Yourdatakeyname means , You have datakeyname="yourColoumnName" in gridviw ,you want to this name in the "yourDataKeyName"

Comment: Ok, so I saw the sample code and follow through. Just one problem, with what shall I replace DataKey in `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
              DataKeyNames="content_id">`

Comment: Your DataBase Table  PrimaryKey name

Comment: Now I don't understand your problem . Please you can understand my 2 link .That solve u r problem!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a while ago myself replacing a predecessors data adapter's with data readers for obvious reasons.

My fix was simple:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
//do stuff
else
//do nothing
GV.DataSource = new DataTable();
```

you're also loading with a datatable, so that should make deploying it easier.

The reason in your specific case is the exception is thrown when no data is passed to the GV.

Comment: And that should be in my download() sub ?

Comment: it would go where you're databinding your gv.